# What type and quantity of steel reinforcement should I place in a slab under a water tower?

Tags: concrete, steel, slab

I want to build a water storage tower
I was going to build a slab about 2.8 meter by 1.8 meter
the tower / storage room would be 2.5 by 1.5 and about 2.5 meters high and built out of concrete blocks and a roof to put a couple of cubes of water on. What size bars should i put in?

kind regards

Comment: Strength of concrete slabs are based on thickness of concrete (depth of rebar from top surface), strength of concrete, total load applied and how the load is applied. So, can you take a pic of the equipment that will sit on the slab and I'm not familiar with the term "couple of cubes"...what is that?

Comment: wanted to build a slab 8 inches thick with re bars in middle and on the slab build a building out off 4 inch concrete blocks about 2.5 meters high on top of there 2 containers with 1000 liters in each

Comment: This slab is a ground bearing slab, right? How does the load come down onto the slab? Are you building walls around the edge of the slab, with a roof then on top; or are you filling the whole of the slab with concrete blocks up to the desired level?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to check to make sure the slab doesn't fail:
1) Soil bearing.
2) ratio of concrete to steel so no cracking occurs. 
(This assumes the slab is poured on-grade and is not spanning a gap, etc.)

1) Total load on soil (I'm in U.S., so I converted your meter dimensions to feet and inches for my calculations):
     Water: 2.2 #/liter x 1,000 liter = 2,200 lbs.
     Block wall: 50 PSF x 8'-6" high x (8'-6" long +
          5'-2" wide) x 2 sides each = 11,650 lbs.
     Slab (estimate 6" thick): 75 psf x 6.2' x 9.6' = 
                                                        = 4,460 lbs. 
     Roof: 15 psf x 8.5' x 5.2' =  680 lbs.
     Miscellaneous: (water container, etc.= 240 lbs.
                                             TOTAL = 18,550 lbs.

Required soil bearing = 18,550/9.6' x 6.2' =311psf

Normal untested soil has a minimum capacity of 1,000 psf, so, unless this is a marsh, you'll be fine.

2) Required ratio of concrete to steel:
     Pe = .0101 x thickness x width (assume 12" so
                  the required area can be calculated 
                  in square inches per foot)

```
 Pe = .0101 x 6" x 12" = 0.727 square inches per foot
```

Therefore, use #6 rebar @ 6" o.c. each way in a 6" thick concrete slab. (I know you were thinking of using 8" thick, but 6" is plenty adequate.)
Here, we measure rebar by 1/8" increments. Therefore, a #6 bar is 6/8" diameter...or 3/4" diameter.

Remember, keep the rebar 3" clear of the ground and hold the rebar back 2" from the edge of the slab. This will protect the rebar and give it proper cover (bonding) by the concrete.

Comment: Oh, I see you're using 2 cubes of water, so the water load should have an additional 2,200 lbs. added to the total load. Still, not significant enough to change the reinforcing. If you decide to stay with the 8" thick slab, I'd increase the steel to #6 bars at 4" o.c. each way.

Comment: What about bending of the slab? Critical if the water tower has walls rather than being solidly filled with blockwork. Also, cover isn't about bonding; it's about resistance to water penetration which causes corrosion of the reinforcement.

Comment: @AndyT   +1 for you to think about corrosion. I think we may be talking about the same thing. live in a “high corrosive “ area and rust is always a concern. However, for me, bonding requirements are generally more restrictive than “cover” requirements. (Smaller bars take less bonding requirements, so less cover). I don’t know everything about cover to eliminate corrosion and rust, but I do know that it has to do with air quality, strength (hardness) of concrete, etc. which usually translates to depth of rebar (cover). This is the same depth or cover we worry about for proper bonding of

Comment: Concrete around rebar for developing full strength.  Also, we don’t worry about “bending” for slab-on-grade construction. Here the slab is only in compression, (unless there’s a soft spot and the slab needs to “span” over the soft spot. In fact, we assume the slab will settle uniformly so there will not be bending.

Comment: With regards to cover: I'm a Chartered Civil Engineer (roughly equivalent to a Professional Engineer in the USA) and have professionally designed structures with a 120 year design life. For these, cover to reduce chances of corrosion is far in excess of that required for bonding. I'll admit to having no professional experience of residential construction, for which I believe design life is more like 50-60 years. I admit it is possible that for these structures that bonding might be the critical requirement.

Comment: With regards bending: perhaps you have misunderstood my comment. If the slab supports walls at the edges, but nothing in the middle, then this is the upside-down equivalent of a slab supported on walls at the edge, with a uniformly distributed load on the middle. It would therefore experience bending. If, however, the ground-bearing slab has a uniform load on top of it (i.e. solid construction, no walls) then you are 100% correct that the slab is only in compression. I don't believe the OP has given enough information on the construction of the water tower and have left him a comment about it.

Comment: @AndyT  Yes...+1 for knowing that distinction. If the water is in a tank with legs or on walls, it will have bending. For some reason I assumed the water was inside the container “built out of concrete blocks with a roof on it” and covered the slab.